# Excel Conditional Formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, data-validation

Highlight all non-blank entries in a column, except for the column header, that do no fall in some range.
Here's my attempt:

```
=AND(OR(VALUE(INDIRECT("H"&ROW()))<0,VALUE(INDIRECT("H"&ROW()))>100),ROW()>1)
```

Evaluates as expected if pasted in a cell. Used in conditional formatting does not.
Anybody knows why?

Comment: Any feedback always appreciated. I beg you do not just cast a mute down vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select **whole column H** and use this formula in conditional formatting

`=OR(H1<0,H1>100)`

That will adjust automatically for each row (you don't need `INDIRECT` here)

Unless H1 is a number that satisfies the conditions you don't need to exclude H1, if it is then change the "applies to" range as Raystafarian suggests

Comment: That worked fine. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

it looks like you're trying to get values less than zero or greater than 1, so you can look at it as **not between**

the easy way to do this is without a formula: `conditional formatting - highlight cell rules - more rules` go with `cell value` and `not between` `0` and `1` and hit okay

if you want to exclude the header go to `conditional formatting - manage rules` and change the `applies to` range.

[link to some good info](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/cformatting.htm)

Comment: Cheers for that. However it seems to me that it highlights blank cells too. Any thoughts on that

Comment: Make sure your blank cells are actually blank. Try moving your data to a new worksheet and see if it still happens, it shouldn't

Comment: No luck, it does it on all worksheets :(

Comment: Open a new workbook, create some new data and apply the formatting. See if it behaves the same when you do that. It shouldn't.

Comment: Exactly the same thing. I have created a new file, not only a new workbook this time, all blank cells highlighted.